# Error: ‘O_CREATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux, signals, producer-consumer

The following code is supposed to synchronize two processes, a producer that writes some integers, and a consumers that reads them, now when executing it gives me this error:

```
‘O_CREATE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

But I have included the `fcntl.h`, what else might be the problem?

```
int main(void) 
{
int fd, n, i; 
pid_t pid, ppid; 
char buf[1];
if((fd=open("/tmp/data_file", O_APPEND|O_CREATE, 0640)) <0) exit(1);
sigset(SIGTERM,SIG_IGN);/* signal */   ; sigset(SIGINT,SIG_IGN); /* signal */ 
pid=fork(); 
switch (pid) { 
    case -1: { perror(“FORK”); exit(1); }
    case 0: /* child process - Producer */ 
        sigset(SIGUSR1,wakeup);   
        sighold(SIGUSR1);       /* block / hold signals SIGUSR1 until sigpause*/ 
        for (i=0; i<=100; i++) { 
            /* sleep a random amount of time */ 
            n = (int)(getpid()%256); 
            srand((unsigned)n); 
            sleep(rand() %5);
            /* writes a character in file */ 
            sprintf(buf,"%d",i); 
            write(fd, buf,sizeof(buf)); 
            fprintf(stderr,"Producer PID=%d value = %d\n",getpid(), i); 
            ppid=getppid(); 
            kill(ppid, SIGUSR2);    
            sigpause(SIGUSR1);  /* pause(); until SIGUSR! received*/ 
        }  
break;


default:    /* -parent code - Consumer */ 
        sigset(SIGUSR2,wakeup);
        sighold(SIGUSR2);       /* block / hold signals SIGUSR2 until sigpause*/ 
        for (i=0; i<=100; i++) { 
            /* sleep a random amount of time */ 
            n = (int)(getpid()%256); 
            srand((unsigned)n); 
            sleep(rand() %5);
            sigpause(SIGUSR2); /* pause(); */ 
            /* reads a character from file */ 
            read(fd, buf,sizeof(buf)); 
            fprintf(stderr,"Consumer PID=%d value=%d\n",getpid(),atoi(buf));
            kill(pid, SIGUSR1) ;
} 
break; 
} 
exit(0); 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The macro name should be `O_CREAT`, not `O_CREATE`.

And yes, I hate these names in Unix world, too.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kenneth_Thompson)

> Ken Thompson was once asked what he would do differently if he were redesigning the UNIX system. His reply: "I'd spell `creat` with an `e`."

Comment: lol thats mean by them :P

it now says that there are errors in using the exit()
incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]
what does that mean???

Comment: @TIMTAYLOR Did you `#include <stdlib.h>` ?